# ruby quicksort error

Tags: ruby

below is my quicksort implementation in ruby(using the first element as pivot). But there's an error I cannot figure out why

```
def quicksort(items)
   return items if items.nil? or items.length <= 1

   first=items[0]

   left,right=parti(items,0,items.length)

   quicksort(left) + [first] + quicksort(right)

end

def parti(s,l,r)
  p=s[l]
  i=l+1
  (l+1..r).each do |x|
      if s[x] < p
          s[x],s[i] = s[i],s[x]
          i+=1
      end
  end
  s[l],s[i-1] = s[i-1],s[l]
  return [s[0..i-2],s[i..r]]
end
```

The error:

```
putarray.rb:38:in `block in parti': undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass (NoM
hodError)
      from inputarray.rb:37:in `each'
      from inputarray.rb:37:in `parti'
      from inputarray.rb:22:in `quicksort'
      from inputarray.rb:47:in `<main>'
```

it says in

```
 if s[x] < p
```

s[x] is NilClass.

UPDATE: It turns out

```
left,right=parti(items,0,items.length) should be 
left,right=parti(items,0,items.length-1)
```

But after this change, an error

```
inputarray.rb:37: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

point to

```
(l+1..r).each do |x|
```

Didn't find any good explanation on the internet.

Comment: Presumably `x` is "outside the bounds" of the data so `s[x]` evaluates to `nil` (which is the only instance of `NilClass`). Now, the *why* is for you ;-)

Comment: The quickets way to debug this would be to insert: `puts "#{s.length}, #{x}"` right before the `if s[x] < p`. The last line of output before the exception will be probably have the same numbers. meaning it will output something like "5, 5". I haven't groked your code completely, but I have the feeling your right bound is off by one.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that in Ruby, array index starts from 0, not 1.

Therefore `items.length` will return the value of 1 greater than the maximum index in the array.

Try `right=parti(items,0,items.length-1)` instead of `right=parti(items,0,items.length)`.

Comment: That's true. I changed to items.length-1. But then there's "stack level too deep" error point at this line: (l+1..r).each do |x|

Comment: "stack level too deep" often happens, when you are in an infinite  loop or recursion. As for why this is happening, I am not sure. I am somewhat suspicious of `p=s[l]`. Is your pivot always `p=s[1]`. Shouldn't it update?

Comment: I'm using first element for pivot, so the 2nd argument of parti is 0. so l=0 always

Comment: As a debugging technique, you can try `puts "#{s[x]} - #{s[i]}"` and try to find out why the code is failing.